# environment variable not set in makefile

Tags: makefile, environment-variables

I want to trigger unit test and integration test in a Makefile, my current implementation is like this:

```
all: unittest integration
unittest:
    $(ECHO) @echo 'Running unittest'
    @unset TYPE
    @nosetests
integration:
    $(ECHO) @echo 'Running integration test'
    @export TYPE=integration
    @nosetests
```

but I'm having problems with setting environment variables, when I run `make integration` , the `TYPE` environment variable would not be set, if I set the environment variable manually with `export TYPE=integration`, then I run `make unittest`, the environment variable would not be unset. How to solve this?

Comment: Putting @ before every command is an antipattern which prevents all debugging. Remove them and run with `make -s` when you get things working.

Comment: Why is this tagged `python`? Is there anything Python specific or is it rather generic. Then I would suggest to remove the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each command in a recipe is run in a separate shell. The shell which runs `export TYPE` immediately exits; then the next command is run in a new, fresh instance, which of course does not have this setting.

The shell has specific syntax for setting a variable for the duration of one command; use that.

```
all: unittest integration
unittest:
    echo 'Running unittest'
    TYPE= nosetests
integration:
    echo 'Running integration test'
    TYPE=integration nosetests
```

Incidentally, you should not use upper case for your own variables; these names are reserved for system use.